# What is 'The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h'?

Tags: dataflow

My dataflow job was triggered from Apache_beam of Python.  It was worked when the runner is default, but was failed when the runner is DataFlowRunner.  I wonder some of dataflow setup is not correct in GCP project.

```
insertId: "18yr612ckq8"  
labels: {
dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id: "2019-12-29_20_13_18-6351782926232365732"   
dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name: "wordcountpy-test"   
dataflow.googleapis.com/region: "us-central1"   
}
logName: "projects/hsbc-9820327-cmbsp54-dev/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-12-30T05:13:27.146833360Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id: "2019-12-29_20_13_18-6351782926232365732"    
   job_name: "wordcountpy-test"    
   project_id: "488006911152"    
   region: "us-central1"    
   step_id: ""    
  }
  type: "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h. You can get help with Cloud Dataflow at   https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support."  
 timestamp: "2019-12-30T05:13:25.787782564Z" enter code here
```

Comment: I would recommend looking for more logs or opening a ticket with support. The information here is not sufficient to debug.

Comment: Are you [installing any dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) via `--requirements_file`, `--extra_package` or `--setup_file`?